# Quarantine status in Azure Active Directory sync

Tags: entra-id

In January I installed AAD Cloud Sync Agent and it worked till the end of July.
Checking Azure AD in the cloud the domain is in quarantine status and the installed agents list reports none. First question: was my agent, which worked for months, automatically removed from the list ?

Executing **AAD Cloud Sync Agent Wizard** again it reports the following error:

> PowerShell: System.Net.WebException: Remote server error: (401) Unauthorized.
> in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> in Microsoft.ApplicationProxy.Connector.PSModule.OnpremisesPublishingOperations.ProcessRequestWithoutPayload(HttpWebRequest request)
> in Microsoft.ApplicationProxy.Connector.PSModule.GetPublishedResourceCommand.ProcessRecord()
> in System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

The agent log is full of the following errors:

> AADConnectProvisioningAgent.exe Error: 0 : Service bootstrap request failed with exception. Request Id: 'fa4d8a82-150a-4326-a556-ccf43b1a9f45', Error: 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: La richiesta HTTP non è autorizzata con lo schema di autenticazione client 'Anonymous'. Intestazione di autenticazione ricevuta dal server: ''. ---> System.Net.WebException: Errore del server remoto: (401) Non autorizzato.
> in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)

It is not a TLS 1.2 problem because it is not mandatory yet.
Admin AAD login has been verified.
The public ip of AAD agent on premise may have changed, is it possible the requests fail because the ip is filtered ?

Comment: Open a support case in your Office 365 tenant. It's completely free. They'll help you resolve the problem and you'll learn something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

"quarantine status" happens when usually there's a sync problem, which you need to manually address: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-troubleshoot#provisioning-quarantined-problems

Not sure why the agent was removed from the list, it could be removed manually by someone else? check the tenant Audit Logs and hope you see something in the past 30 days.

Translating your error message to English:

> 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The richest
> **HTTP is not authorized with the schema of the 'Anonymous' client
> authentication**. Intestazione di authenticazione ricevuta dal server:
> ''. ---> System.Net.WebException: Errore del remote server: (401) Non
> autorizzato.

Looks like the account you're using is not working or you're passing a proxy, check the user sign-in logs in Azure AD for more details and fix accordingly if it's an auth problem. If you see no data in the logs then then double check if you a have a proxy and configure that in your sync agent settings: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-troubleshoot#agent-times-out-or-certificate-is-invalid

The Azure AD Cloud Sync agent doesn't store any configs locally, so if issue persists, uninstall it completely, review the prerequisites, and then perform a new deployment accordingly: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-prerequisites

Comment: I removed the agent and installed its latest version, but I still had the connection errors. Then I followed Microsoft Support advice to update the server and finally I could see it in the agent list. Despite I have no more connection errors in tre log, the status is **Provisioning quarantined**, but it is another problem.